# Nd4j permute does not permute - what have I done wrong?

Tags: java, nd4j

i am trying to permute an array as described in the [documentation](https://nd4j.org/doc/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.html#permute-int...-) (actual a link to [mathworks](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)).

My code, however does not reproduce the results. Actually, it seems like my code does nothing:

```
INDArray foobar = Nd4j.linspace(0, 2, 3);
System.out.println("foobar = " + foobar);
System.out.println("foobar.permute(2, 1, 0) = " + foobar.permute(2, 1, 0));
```

Output is the same for `foobar` and `foobar.permute`. 
Where did I mess up?

Optional: Any information on how permute work (syntax-wise) with higher dimensions like 2d or 3d matrices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you linked to, permute method is used to permute the dimensions of a multi-dimensional array. Nd4j.linspace creates a vector (a 1-dimensional array). Since there is only one dimension, there is no other dimension to permute it with. The example on Mathworks on the other hand, creates a 3-dimentional array and permutes the 1st and 3rd dimension.

It sounds like your intention was to permute the individual elements of an array (not entire dimensions). I haven't seen a method for that in Nd4j.

Comment: Thx - this was in fact the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't think there is a method inside the Nd4j.
I wrote a method to reorder an ND4j vector.

```
publin INDArray reorder(int[] index) {
        INDArray copy = q.dup();
        for (int i=0; i<copy.length(); i++){
            copy.put(i, q.getScalar(index[i]));
        }
        return copy;
}
```